# SSIS 2012 Deploy Package.... One ETL Used for Many Sites

Tags: ssis

Currently have 1 ETL that is ran through the day for different sites. The etl is launched with different jobs for different sites, so each job has a different config file.

Deploying a project has parameters, so what should I be looking up/reading to find out how to replicate how we normally do it but using the project deployment.

Comment: hmm.. I might have jumped to quick to asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just walking through the steps would have showed me that it's held in the sql agent job as. duh.